# AJAX or Direct Link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

What is the best way to handle Ajax vs. Full page requests with PHP ?

I mean if I click a button that calls Ajax function and loads necessary info into a div and changes the URL.

How do I make that link work if the user copy it and use later to reach the same page.

Comment: You look for the hash in the URL and do the necessary stuff. Your best bet is to get a JavaScript MVC framework that handles it for you.

Answer (score 0):

In some of the apps I separate it with a hash. Something like a router and my code goes something like this:

```
var preRoute = document.URL.split('#');
if(preRoute[1] != undefined) {
  //ajax call
} else {
  //default page
}
```

Comment: or you might want to consider using emberjs :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try Jquery Adress http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/,
demo here
http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/
or
http://vietcode.vn

Answer (score 0):

You could check the headers. jQuery for example will add the following key/value to the header: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` for ajax calls. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-x-requested-with-header)

Answer (score 0):

Using: jquery pjax - https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

you can detect on server side if you get `X-PJAX` request header

And a great feature of this plugin is the history manipulation and ease of use.