# How to determine if it is an AJAX request in Flask

Tags: ajax, flask, jinja2

I am planning to use same templates (Jinja 2) for AJAX and normal requests. If it is an AJAX request I will not use `extends` and for normal request `extends` would be used for extending the base template.

My problem is, how do I differentiate between a normal and an AJAX request? Is there any way I can introspect the `request` object to determine whether the incoming request is AJAX based or a normal request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reliably detect if the request was made via AJAX. Some Javascript libraries may set the `X-Requested-With` header to `XMLHttpRequest`, but since `X-Requested-With` is [not part of the default set of headers that CORS permits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-the-x-requested-with-header), it is falling out of favour.

In older versions of Flask (before version 1.x), [`request.is_xhr`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/api/#flask.Request.is_xhr) was provided to detect if this header is present and set to `XMLHttpRequest`, the defacto API for AJAX requests before the introduction of the Fetch API:

> *True* if the request was triggered via a JavaScript *XMLHttpRequest*. This only works with libraries that support the `X-Requested-With` header and set it to *XMLHttpRequest*. Libraries that do that are prototype, jQuery and Mochikit and probably some more.

Example:

```
{% if not request.is_xhr %}
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% extends "base.html" if not request.is_xhr else "ajax.html" %}
```

In newer versions you'd have to check for the header manually:

```
{% if request.headers.get("X-Requested-With") != "XMLHttpRequest" %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

If you are trying to determine to serve JSON instead of HTML, a more reliable method might be to check if the `Accept` header includes `application/json`, via the [`accept_json` property](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MIMEAccept.accept_json) of the [`request.accept_mimetypes`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Request.accept_mimetypes) object:

```py
# in Python code, in your view, for example:
if request.accept_mimetypes.accept_json:
    ...
```

Comment: `request.is_xhr` has been deprecated, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871003/identify-if-flask-request-is-from-javascript-or-not) for the reasoning and alternative approaches.

Comment: @danialk: thanks for the ping. Not only was it deprecated, it is now firmly gone from recent Flask versions.