# Identify if Flask request is from JavaScript or not

Tags: python, angularjs, ajax, flask

I want to create a Flask error handler that returns a JSON response if the request was from JavaScript but returns a redirect otherwise. I tried using `request.is_xhr`, but it is false even for JavaScript requests. How can I check if the request is from JavaScript?

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def unhandled_exception(error):
    if request.is_xhr:
        return flask.jsonify(error='yes')

    return redirect(url_for('error'))
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard or reliable way to detect if a request comes from a particular source, such as JavaScript.

`is_xhr` was only true when a certain header was set by some JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery. The header is not sent by most JavaScript. `is_xhr` has been deprecated for that reason.

You can check the `Accept` header to see if the client is asking for `application/json`, but that too is unreliable.

```
if request.is_xhr or request.accept_mimetypes.accept_json:
    return jsonify(...)

return redirect(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @davidism makes sense. `is_xhr` was only true when a certain header was set by some JavaScript libraries. So, I have set header 'X-Requested-With' to '`XMLHttpRequest`' manually in `'$httpProvider'` config in `AngularJs`. This ensures that on the back end I will get '`is_xhr`' true for AJAX request.

```
app.config([
    '$httpProvider',
    function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        var interceptor = [
            '$q',
            '$rootScope',
            function ($q, $rootScope) {
                    'responseError': function (rejection) {
                        if(rejection.status != undefined && rejection.status != 'undefined') {
                            window.location.href = '/error';
                        }
                    }
                };
                return service;
            }
        ];
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than tie my app to a non-standard header I added an `Accept:` header to my Javascript instead:

```js
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('POST', location);
// signal back-end to return json instead of rendering a full page:
req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
req.send(…);
```

And in my Python:

```
# if an ajax-like request, return json instead of html
if request.accept_mimetypes.best == 'application/json':
    log.debug('client prefers json, skipping page render.')
    return jsonify(status='errror', detail='…')
```

This should handle other use cases as they come up.

Comment: So, do I need to set request header on every AJAX request??

Comment: Looks like you could try it using the angular `…headers.common…` line above.

Comment: Is there any common place where I can configure for all AJAX calls in angular? Because I have lots of AJAX call in my application and it's difficult for me to find and place everywhere.

Comment: Haven't used it in years, sorry.  But I'd suggest making a single function for ajax calls, and then reusing it everywhere instead.

Answer (score -1):

If the request is from a javascript/jquery code, is it most certainly from a browser so you can check the `flask.request.user_agent` object which is a instance of [`werkzeug.useragents.UserAgent`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/utils/#module-werkzeug.useragents) to verify that.