# Node.js: How to detect html embedded request vs XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

In Node.js (or in any web server for that matter), is it somehow possible to be able to determine whether a resource request came from an embedded element in an html document, as opposed to a scripted request?

For instance, if I have this in my .html file:

```
<script src="/testRoute.js"></script>
```

And this in my javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", '/testRoute.js', true);
xhr.send();
```

is there a way the server can distinguish between these two requests?

The **[Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)** applies differently in each case, so there is apparently some differentiation going on (at least under the surface). Is there a way the server developer can see the difference?

---

Just as a personal experiment, using a diff tool, I compared an **[express](http://expressjs.com/)** `req` object received with each and saw only two slight differences:

1. The `socket`, `connection`, and `client` properties in the
   `<script>` originating `req` object had `[function]`s for their `error` property,
   whereas these were `[object]` for the request that originated as an `XMLHttpRequest`.
2. The `headers` property contained `cache-control: 'max-age=0'` in the request that originated as an `XMLHttpRequest` but not for the `<script>` request.

I don't really know what that means, and I don't know if these results are consistent across browsers, but they were consistent at least between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Yes, the headers might be different. Some frameworks e.g. set the `X-REQUESTED-WITH`-Header on XMLHttpRequests. But in general, no, there is no designated header to tell the difference, both are plain HTTP requests.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! Your comment led to me finding [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-x-requested-with-header) which explains the `X-REQUESTED-WITH` header quite nicely. So does this mean I could add that header myself for each request I want to be distinguishable?

Comment: Yes, if you want the requests to be distinguishable you should set such a header for every ajax call.