# Is just checking the Referer header enough to prevent CSRF?

Tags: python, csrf, csrf-protection

Is comparing the Referer http header enough to prevent CSRF, I have the following html code below.

```html
<div id="Message"></div><br>
Username:<br>
<input type="text" name="Username" id="Username"><br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="Password" id="Password"><br>
Keep me logged in:<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="KeepSessionAlive"><br>
<input type="submit" onClick="ProcessLogin();">
<script>
function ProcessLogin(){
    Username=document.getElementById("Username").value;
    Password=document.getElementById("Password").value;
    KeepSessionAlive=document.getElementById("KeepSessionAlive").value;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("Message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","/Login/Process",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("<A>Username</A><B>"+Username+"</B><A>Password</A><B>"+Password+"</B><A>KeepSessionAlive</A><B>"+KeepSessionAlive+"</B>");
}
</script>
```

It is just a standerd html form but I was wondering if I use the code below can I be completely protected from CSRF attacks.

```
class LoginProcess(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        HTTTP_REFERER=self.request.referer
        if HTTP_REFER=="http://example.com":
            self.response.write('Referer: '+cgi.escape(HTTTP_REFERER))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is enough but it is considered a weaker form of protection:

> Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header on your own
>   browser, it is impossible to do so in a CSRF attack. Checking the
>   referer is a commonly used method of preventing CSRF on embedded
>   network devices because it does not require a per-user state. This
>   makes a referer a useful method of CSRF prevention when memory is
>   scarce. This method of CSRF mitigation is also commonly used with
>   unauthenticated requests, such as requests made prior to establishing
>   a session state which is required to keep track of a synchronization
>   token.
>
> However, checking the referer is considered to be a weaker from of
>   CSRF protection. For example, open redirect vulnerabilities can be
>   used to exploit GET-based requests that are protected with a referer
>   check and some organizations or browser tools remove referrer headers
>   as a form of data protection. There are also common implementation
>   mistakes with referer checks. For example if the CSRF attack
>   originates from an HTTPS domain then the referer will be omitted. In
>   this case the lack of a referer should be considered to be an attack
>   when the request is performing a state change. Also note that the
>   attacker has limited influence over the referer. For example, if the
>   victim's domain is "site.com" then an attacker have the CSRF exploit
>   originate from "site.com.attacker.com" which may fool a broken referer
>   check implementation. XSS can be used to bypass a referer check.
>
> In short, referer checking is a reasonable form of CSRF intrusion
>   detection and prevention even though it is not a complete protection.
>   Referer checking can detect some attacks but not stop all attacks. For
>   example, if you HTTP referrer is from a different domain and you are
>   expecting requests from your domain only, you can safely block that
>   request.

If you want a "quick method" of preventing CSRF from XHR you could set and check a custom header such as [`X-Requested-With`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533680/413180). This is presently secure, however the recommended approach is the [Synchronizer Token Pattern](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern). This is more robust against flaws in browser plugins, such as an [old vulnerability in Flash](http://www.securityfocus.com/archive/1/441014/30/0/threaded) that allowed headers to be set that shouldn't normally be possible.