# XMLHttpRequest() not recognized as a IsAjaxRequest?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

To redirect user to sign in page when session timed out for Ajax request, I implemented following custom attribute,

Code related to Unauthorize request is as follows,

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        Error = "SessionTimeOut"
                    },
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
....................
```

This works fine for ajax requests ($.ajax).

But filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() does not recognize XMLHttp request as an ajax request.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('POST', "...URL");
                xhr.send(formdata);
```

Does anyone came across similar issue? what would be a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code for `IsAjaxRequest()` in ASP.NET MVC 5

```
public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
    if (request == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    }
    return request["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest" || (request.Headers != null && request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest");
}
```

It looks like there is a dependency on a certain header value (`X-Requested-With`) being in the request in order for that function to return true.

Here is some more info on `X-Requested-With`

[What's the point of the X-Requested-With header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-x-requested-with-header)

You could always look at the jQuery `$.ajax()` code itself to see how that is setting the header. To be honest, I wouldn't bother doing ajax without jQuery anyway, it deals with all of these things for you.

Comment: Yes you are correct, in my case, in a WebWorker I have to use XMLHttpRequest instead $.ajax, then I'm using that header:
`var _XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
`_XMLHttpRequest.open("POST", ..., true);
` _XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("__RequestVerificationToken", ...);
` _XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
` _XMLHttpRequest.responseType = 'json';
` _XMLHttpRequest.send(...);