# Is a HTTP GET the same thing as an AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, http-get

This is something I was wondering, but could not get a definitive answer elsewhere.

Is a http get request asynchronous?
If they're different, are there any major differences?

Not looking for opinions, just definitive answers.
Googling has just repeatedly led me to examples of one or the other.

Comment: Do you mean the literal difference between AJAX and HTTP verbs? Or do you mean the difference between `$.ajax()`, `$.get()` etc? The long story short is that AJAX is an asynchronous way of performing a GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTTP** is the most common protocol used to transfer data on the web.  It's what the browser users on port 80 for all websites.  Pages, AJAX, etc.

**GET** is a particular "verb" used in an HTTP request.  A GET request is usually distinct in that it doesn't have a request body and it doesn't expect to modify anything on the server, simply "get" data.

**AJAX** requests are essentially HTTP requests made from JavaScript code, rather than from navigation in the browser.  They may be GET requests, or they may be other kinds of HTTP requests.  Structurally they're no different from any other HTTP request made by the browser, they're just made from code instead of the browser's UI.

---

There is overlap between these three terms, because they're not mutually exclusive versions of the same thing.  They're apples and oranges, really.  HTTP isn't different from the other two, it would be different from something like FTP.  GET isn't different from the other two, it would be different from something like POST.

You can see a lot of this in action by taking a look at your browser's debugging tools.  Visiting any reasonably active page (such as Stack Overflow, for example) will show you a number of requests being made and the server's responses to those requests.  As you interact with a page which uses AJAX, watch those requests in the debugging tools and see how they're structured.  Load a page or two by navigation and see how those requests are structured.

There's not much to it, really.  It's all requests and responses, each of which is simply headers and content.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this explained a few things, was mainly just looking for the subtle differences, which this explained.

Answer (score 0):

[Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) used so web applications can send data to and retrieve from a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page.

`HTTP GET` or `HTTP POST` are method in the [HTTP Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), which are a way to send and receive the data.

While `Ajax` is the **Car**, `HTTP Protocol` is the **Driving laws**.

Few examples of everyday surfing using `Ajax`:

- **Facebook Feed** - When scrolling to the bottom of *Facebook* a Loader circle appears that loads a more prior updates on your wall, this is happening without surfing to another page, but rather retrieving it while still on the same page.
- **Google Omnibox Prediction** - When typing part of the text in the Omnibox, google will suggest you the completion of your text while you're still typing.

Comment: That analogy isn't really ideal.

Answer (score 0):

First try to get through : [GET vs POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

An ajax call can be GET or POST or PUT or any other.

To differentiate between ajax GET & normal HTTP GET.

1. Ajax GET seems asynchronous by as the request is sent using another thread by the browser.
2. Ajax GET request has additional [`X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-x-requested-with-header).
3. GET Request is captured by browser history, whilw Ajax GET does not get captured.

Comment: ~10k rep and suggesting w3schools link ?

Comment: @NullPoiиteя - i checked the content of that page specifically before sharing, i am curious too while sharing w3s pages. seems ok with the nature of question being asked.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this cleared things up a bit. Unfortunately I can't upvote yet, but will make sure do so once i'm allowed to.