# Using digest of your site's authentication cookie for CSRF

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, csrf

I want to protect my WebApi endpoints against CSRF. Angular team recommends  to use digest of your site's authentication cookie with a salt for added security. I'm not sure what's the advantage here comparing to random token. What is more, how do you protect login page?

Here is explanation why do you need to protect login page https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2120/when-the-use-of-a-antiforgerytoken-is-not-required-needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're describing is [detailed here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection XSRF is a technique by
>   which an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data. Angular
>   provides a mechanism to counter XSRF. When performing XHR requests,
>   the $http service reads a token from a cookie (by default, XSRF-TOKEN)
>   and sets it as an HTTP header (X-XSRF-TOKEN). Since only JavaScript
>   that runs on your domain could read the cookie, your server can be
>   assured that the XHR came from JavaScript running on your domain. The
>   header will not be set for cross-domain requests.
>
> To take advantage of this, your server needs to set a token in a
>   JavaScript readable session cookie called XSRF-TOKEN on the first HTTP
>   GET request. On subsequent XHR requests the server can verify that the
>   cookie matches X-XSRF-TOKEN HTTP header, and therefore be sure that
>   only JavaScript running on your domain could have sent the request.
>   The token must be unique for each user and must be verifiable by the
>   server (to prevent the JavaScript from making up its own tokens). We
>   recommend that the token is a digest of your site's authentication
>   cookie with a salt for added security.
>
> The name of the headers can be specified using the xsrfHeaderName and
>   xsrfCookieName properties of either $httpProvider.defaults at
>   config-time, $http.defaults at run-time, or the per-request config
>   object.
>
> In order to prevent collisions in environments where multiple Angular
>   apps share the same domain or subdomain, we recommend that each
>   application uses unique cookie name.

This appears to be a variation on the [Encrypted Token Pattern CSRF prevention method](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Encrypted_Token_Pattern), using hashing rather than encryption, and the salt is acting like the secret key.

It also relies upon a HTTP feature that prevents custom headers from being sent cross domain, much like adding [`X-Requested-With`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533680/413180) does.

The part that states "an unauthorized site can gain your user's private data" is slightly misleading, as CSRF does not allow this directly - a CSRF attack allows an unauthorized site to submit your site's forms in the context of the currently logged in user.

An advantage of this method is that you do not need to save anything extra server side. For example, if you are using [token-based](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/) authentication you can easily verify that the CSRF token received matches the cookie by applying the same hash with the server-side salt. Even if you are using cookie-based authentication you do not need to verify the CSRF token against a separate value stored server-side - you simply hash the cookie value to verify that it matches the passed token.

See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/59529/8340) for how to protect against login CSRF.

Comment: What I don't get is why hash(cookie + salt) is better than random string. If someone has access to cookies you are screwed https://gist.github.com/lukasz-madon/53a4a89a738ffb7c85e7

Comment: CSRF is a completely different attack vector than one that gives access to cookies. If the latter is a concern, then you should not lose sleep about csrf until this hypothetical high risk vulnerability is fixed. It is not necessarily "better" but has the advantage that no server side state is needed.