# How to create an XML Http Request?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In phoenixframework, I need to create a post request, to send parameters to another server.

As I am newcomer to elixir, I am wondering how would I do so? is there a library for this purpose? or is it possible to initiate a post request without installing a new library? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use libraries such as [httpoison](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison) to make http requests from any elixir code.

Note that `XMLHttpRequest` is a browser api for making http requests (and it's been a long time since it wasn't XML specific at all) - there's nothing 'special' about those requests in general. Many js libraries (including Jquery, prototype, etc) add a [`X-Requested-With` header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-the-x-requested-with-header) but that's just a convention.

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered httpc in erlang, do you encourage me to use :httpc or httpoison ?

Comment: There are quite a few others ( https://github.com/h4cc/awesome-elixir#http ) - I don't know enough to recommend one over another. httpoison has worked fine for me