# Fetch API Global Error Handler

Tags: javascript, fetch, es6-promise

I am using the fetch API with a REST API, and i want to handle certain errors globally, errors like `500, 503 ...` I tried doing something like this

```
function(url, method, data) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method || "GET",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }
    }).then(response => {

        if (response.ok && response.status < 500) console.log("ouch");;

        return response;

});
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. **how do i catch `500, 503 ...` in the fetch api?**

Comment: `it doesn't seem to be working` in what way? it doesn't look like you're handling any errors at all - also, you've got a function expression there ... clearly not actual code as that isn't allowed like that (although, the last line `});` suggests this snippet is just a poorly chosen fragment of your actual code)

Comment: fetch is a promise event so any error must caught in catch statement

Comment: @NavdeepSingh yeah i want something like a global `catch` and `then`

Comment: Create a `fetch` wrapper that supports global / top-level response interceptors / error handlers. Or you know, just use Axios.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this approach in this way you can handle all possible errors at one place and you also can generate custom response to return e.g if your all requests return JSON data then you can convert response to JSON before returning it.

```js
function secureFetch(url, method, data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: method || "GET",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      // response only can be ok in range of 2XX
      if (response.ok) {
        // you can call response.json() here too if you want to return json
        resolve(response);
      } else {
        //handle errors in the way you want to
        switch (response.status) {
          case 404:
            console.log('Object not found');
            break;
          case 500:
            console.log('Internal server error');
            break;
          default:
            console.log('Some error occured');
            break;
        }

        //here you also can thorow custom error too
        reject(response);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      //it will be invoked mostly for network errors
      //do what ever you want to do with error here
      console.log(error);
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

secureFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(error => console.log(error));

secureFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/100000000')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json))
.catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: In case you want to stop redirect to auth on ajax, probably you need a popular but non-standard [header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478731/whats-the-point-of-the-x-requested-with-header) `X-Requested-With` and catch 401 Unauthorized. Otherwise you'll get 302 found redired and then uncatchable Type error.

Answer (score -1):

Here you can handle with promise something like this:

```js
function status(response) {
    /*You can handle status here.*/
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
    }
  }

  function json(response) {
    return response.json()
  }
function makeCall(url, method, data) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method || "GET",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        }
    })
    .then(status)
    .then(json)
    .then(function(data) {
     console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('Request failed', error);
    });
}

var url = 'http://localhost:4200/profile';
var data = {username: 'example'};
makeCall(url, 'POST', data);
```