# How to handle the CSRF when implementing Google Identity Services popup code model?

Tags: google-authentication, google-identity

On my site I have implemented Google Identity Services using a [popup code model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model#popup-mode).

To prevent CSRF attacks the docs say this:

> With Popup mode, you add a custom HTTP header to your requests, and
> then on your server confirm it matches the expected value and origin.

Here is the popup sample code provided in the docs:

```JavaScript
const client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
  client_id: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID',
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
  ux_mode: 'popup',
  callback: (response) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', code_receiver_uri, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // Set custom header for CRSF
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XmlHttpRequest');
    xhr.onload = function() {
      console.log('Auth code response: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('code=' + code);
  },
});
```

It's my understanding that I need to add a random CSRF code string to the above code, and then verify that on my server.

**But where exactly do I put that CSRF code?**

I thought that maybe it should go in the `code` variable like this `xhr.send('code=' + 'MY_CSRF_STRING')` but when I do that my headers look like this (`MY_CSRF_STRING` is missing so I cannot verify it on the server):

```
{
   "host":"localhost:5001",
   "connection":"keep-alive",
   "accept":"*/*",
   "access-control-request-method":"POST",
   "access-control-request-headers":"x-requested-with",
   "origin":"http://localhost:8080",
   "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36",
   "sec-fetch-mode":"cors",
   "sec-fetch-site":"same-site",
   "sec-fetch-dest":"empty",
   "referer":"http://localhost:8080/",
   "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
   "accept-language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
   "severity":"INFO",
   "message":"googleAuthorization req.headers"
}
```

**And if the CSRF code does not go there, what else is supposed to go in the `code` variable?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I figured this out.

But I would still love to hear from others to make sure this is correct.

In short, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22533680/1526396) outlines that the csrf protection comes from checking for the existance of the custom `X-Requested-With` header. No need to create your own unique value.

There is also a typo in the Google code sample which created this confusion.

The line `xhr.send('code=' + code);` should be `xhr.send('code=' + response.code);`. Because we are taking the auth code from the response and passing it along to the server.