# I get an error when I use Axios to access a third-party API, but fetch() does the job

Tags: javascript, axios

Recently, I wanted to get data from a third-party API using Axios. I've got a CORS error. So I decided to use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) instead.

Here is the code. **Function that uses `fetch()`:**

```js
// function that uses fetch()
export default async function () {
    let ipData = await fetch(
        'https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=<key>'
    );
    let parsedIpData = await ipData.json();
    console.log(parsedIpData);
    if (parsedIpData && parsedIpData.languages) {
        parsedIpData.languages.forEach((lang) => {
            if (lang.code == 'en' || lang.code == 'ru') {
                console.log('lang.code - ' + lang.code);
                return lang.code;
            } else {
                console.log('fallback locale - en');
                return 'en';
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log('no response. fallback locale - en');
        return 'en';
    }
}
```

**Function that uses Axios:**

```js
// function that uses Axios
export default async function () {
    axios.get(
        'https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=<key>'
    ).then((response) => {
        if (response && response.languages) {
            response.languages.forEach((lang) => {
                if (lang.code == 'en' || lang.code == 'ru') {
                    console.log('lang.code - ' + lang.code);
                    return lang.code;
                } else {
                    console.log('fallback locale - en');
                    return 'en';
                }
            })
        } else {
            console.log('no response. fallback locale - en');
            return 'en';
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

And here is my error. I've tried to pass headers to `axios.get()` already, but the server didn't allow them.
[image]

Comment: Erm, both axios *and* `fetch` obey CORS restrictions. Anything that runs in the browser does. It's a browser-enforced restriction, not just an artefact of whatever you use to do the requests. CORS would be quite useless if the built-in function to make requests didn't have to obey it.

Comment: @VLAZ, you're right, but I didn't get any CORS errors when I used `fetch()`. Do you know any reasons why that happened? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: CORS has nothing to do with the kind of library you use to do a HTTP request. CORS is a browser security mechanism. Try to reproduce this with two code samples, although it should not be possible.

Comment: @Angelina — We don't know what is different between your fetch and axios tests. Maybe you didn't try to read the data with one. Maybe you used different URLs to it as a same origin request.

Comment: @n9iels, @Quentin, I've just tried to say that I couldn't make a cross-domain request with Axios, and fetch() worked for me. I don't know exactly why. Also, `fetch()` didn't require any additional config to do the job. I'll edit the post soon and show you the pieces of code.

Comment: @Angelina — Fetch and Axios both implement CORS (the latter by proxy as it is a wrapper around XHR). They have the same defaults for any CORS related setting and need the same configuration (although the syntax may vary slightly) for anything like `withCredentials`.

Comment: @Quentin, I'm just getting IP data. Also, I've just edited the post.

Comment: This looks like you have some code, which you didn't include in the question, which tries to set a non-standard `x-requested-with` header on your axios code. Axios doesn't set that by default. (Note that `x-request-with` is a horrible hack designed to tell the server "I want data for Ajax not for a regular page" which `api.ipdata.co` certainly isn't going to do with. HTTP has a standard `Accept` header which can say "I want JSON in the response" which is a much better way to get the same effect (most servers don't do content negotiation though).

Comment: The aforementioned code that you didn't include probably interacts with https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults

Comment: @Quentin, I don't set this header anywhere else, I'm sure. [Here](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst) is the repo of the project where I use this function.

Comment: @Quentin, I also didn't set config defaults.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/tiyugimaji/edit?html,js,output — The code you provided does not generate a preflight request and then fail saying it wasn't allowed to set `x-requested-by` (it does get a CORS error, but that's on the GET request, not the preflight options request, and I assume its because I don't have a real API key).

Comment: Aside: `axios` returns a promise. Wrapping it in a Promise constructor is inefficient and makes things harder to debug.

Comment: @Quentin, I can give you the key if you want. Someone recommended me not posting it. Also, thank you for advice!

Comment: I don't need the key. My point is that the code you've provided doesn't have the problem you say it does. I have no idea why `x-requested-by` is trying to be included on the request, but it isn't caused by any of the code you've shared.

Comment: @Quentin, all the requests I make are [here](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst/tree/main/resources/js/store/modules), in Vuex store modules (`auth`, `resetPassword` and `users` modules only).

Comment: @Quentin, I forgot to mention that I use interceptors [here](https://github.com/loglinn05/catalyst/blob/main/resources/js/axios/axiosInstance.js).

Comment: @Angelina do you get the same error if you remove this interceptor? You can also try adding `Authorization` header to the fetch request to see if it results in the same error

Comment: @Konrad, yes, I get the same error even when I remove the interceptor. I've also added `Authorization` header to the fetch request, and it didn't result in an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is updated. Look at the end of it, please.**

It turned out that Axios always sent requests with `X-Requested-With` header, but it wasn't allowed at the server. Look at the screenshot below to make sure.

[image]

So I decided to assign `null` to `X-Requested-With` header. I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do, so, please, feel free to educate me on this, if you want. Here is how `axios.get()` looks now:

```js
axios.get(
    'https://api.ipdata.co/?api-key=<key>', {
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': null
        }
    }
).then((response) => {
    if (response.data && response.data.languages) {
        console.log(response.data.languages);
        response.data.languages.forEach((lang) => {
            if (lang.code == 'en' || lang.code == 'ru') {
                console.log('lang.code - ' + lang.code);
                return lang.code;
            } else {
                console.log('fallback locale - en');
                return 'en';
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.log(response);
        console.log('no response. fallback locale - en');
        return 'en';
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

And it worked! I'm so glad! Thank you, everyone, for leading me to this answer!

P.S.: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17478731/18630923) helped me to understand the reason Axios and other libraries include `X-Requested-With` into request headers.

**UPDATE:**

[@Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/quentin), you were right! Axios default headers were set in `resources/js/bootstrap.js`. But I didn't create or modify this file.

```js
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
// window.Pusher = Pusher;

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
//     wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ? import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST : `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
//     wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
//     wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
//     forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
//     enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
// });
```